# Couldn't find preset "module:react-native-dotenv"

Tags: react-native, detox

I setup a test with Detox, but when I launch it with `detox test`, the test starts but I receive this error:

`Couldn't find preset "module:react-native-dotenv" relative to directory "/Users/iota/workspace/Project"`

In the scene file I am trying to test I have this:
`import { BASE_URL, GOOGLE_APP_ID } from 'react-native-dotenv';`

My `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:react-native-dotenv",
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ]
}
```

Any hint?

**UPDATE**

If I remove the line `module:react-native-dotenv`, I have a similar error for the `module:metro-react-native-babel-preset`

Comment: If you're using babel7 then you need to add `module:react-native-dotenv` to your `babelrc` file

Comment: Yep, I know, thank you. I updated  my question. I forgot to say that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install the presets using npm, so a

```
npm install --save-dev metro-react-native-babel-preset react-native-dotenv
```

should solve the issue.